# Sometimes Asp.Net Button Fires Event, Sometimes Not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to make a form-check but submit button (asp:Button) sometimes fires target method and sometimes not. I recorded my debugging operation and uploaded it to YouTube, please watch it first to understand what's going on: [YouTube Link >>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEAh4HDVsa4)

I'm really confused about it. Is it just about concurrency or what? What to do? Suggestions? Thanks!

*Button Code:*

```
<asp:Button ID="RegisterButton" OnClick="Register" Text="Register" CssClass="button" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't click the button on the one that didn't fire, you pressed return on the keyboard. Check your button is inside a form with runat="server".

Comment: Oh! You saved a lot of time for me :)